# Sideways Button On Edge of Screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a button to the edge of the screen like this:

[image]

I tried using something like the code below but since the rotation is around the center there is space on the right side of the button about half the length of the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'll do some layout testing, but it'd be helpful if you posted your layout file. @dt0     
<br><br>
EDIT: Rotation doesn't seem to work on TextViews or Buttons, but I am able to mimic your picture with a View.

Comment: I updated with a small sample layout. After fiddling with it for awhile, it seems setting a negative right margin works but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout` to access the attribute `layout_alignParentEnd` for your `Button`. If your root layout is a `RelativeLayout` then use that, if not you can wrap your `Button` in a `RelativeLayout` and use that layout. If you choose the latter option, you will need to position that layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id+/wrapper_or_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:rotation="270"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still has the same problem with the space at the edge because of the rotation around the center.

Comment: Make sure to set `android:paddingRight="0dp"`

Comment: Perhaps the parent layout has a margin or padding.

Comment: Yeah, setting the padding doesn't work. It's definitely because the button rotates around the center. If I use a longer text, the space is longer.